# Joomla query - Select from content where state is published

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

I need to show all published joomla articles with the category id = 43. My query:

```
<?php
    $catId = 43;
    $state = 1;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid ='" . $catId . "' order by title asc";
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $db->setQuery($query); 
    $articles = $db->loadObjectList(); 
    foreach($articles as $article) {
        echo 'Content';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add state condition :

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid ='" . $catId . "' and state = 1 order by title asc";
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where state = 1 order by title asc' at line 1 SQL=SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid ='43' where state = 1 order by title asc